# How to setAttribute of DOMDocument element with special characters?

Tags: php, domdocument, setattribute

In an HTML block such as this:

```
<p>Hello: <img src="hello/foo.png" /></p>
```

I need to transform the URL `src` of the image to a Laravel `storage_path` link. I'm using PHP DOMDocument to transform the url like so:

```
$link = $a->getAttribute('src');
$pat = '#(\w+\.\w+)+(?!.*(\w+)(\.\w+)+)#';
$matches = [];
preg_match($pat, $link, $matches);
$newStr = "{{ storage_path('app/' . " . $matches[0] . ") }}";
$a->setAttribute('src', $newStr);
```

The problem is that the output is `src="%7B%7B%20storage_path('app/'%20.%20foo.png)%20%7D%7D"`

How can I keep the special characters of the `src` attribute?

Comment: Are you going to close this answer too ?

Comment: @PedroLobito if by answer you mean question, yes I would if I find a duplicate on SO before anyone answers.. is that not expected?

Comment: That looks like URL encoding. I would be surprised if DOMDocument does this. Is there something else that might decide 'src' needs to be url encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$html = '<p>Hello: <img src="hello/foo.png" /></p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$img->item(0)->setAttribute('src', '{{ storage_path(\'app/\' . foo.png) }}');
#loadHTML causes a !DOCTYPE tag to be added, so remove it:
$dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);
#it also wraps the code in <html><body></body></html>, so remove that:
$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);
$newImage = urldecode($dom->saveHTML());
//<p>Hello: <img src="{{ storage_path('app/' . foo.png) }}"></p>
```

---

**Note:**
In order to output the `img` `src` as you want, you'll need to use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I need to rewrite the URL to point to Laravel storage folder (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-storage-path)